# Arduino does not make any sound when connected to laptop?

Tags: arduino-uno

When I connect my Arduino through USB to my laptop, it does not make any sound like something is connected but green light is on. And port option in the Arduino IDE remains grayed out. I might have burned my Arduino, maybe? Please help.

Comment: Can you try 1) a different cable, 2) connecting to a different computer, or 3) a different Arduino? Has anything happened to the Arduino to make you suspect any damage? It does sound like a problem with the communication processor on the Arduino board, but best to be sure.

Comment: An Arduino never makes a sound when connected.  Any such sound would be a function of the host operating system, which you have neglected to even mention in your question.

Comment: Is this a *real* Arduino, or a cheap Chinese CH340G based BoS?

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino will not make a sound, but probably you refer to the sound Windows makes when a USB device is connected?

Try (except for the tips already given by JRobert)

- different USB port
- reinstall Arduino IDE
- disable/enable or reinstall driver in Control panel/hardware/system/USB devices

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possible scenarios as to what is wrong:

1. The USB cable is a power only cable and has no data lines. However, this is unlikely because, whilst power-only USB cables are common with mobile phones (i.e. USB to Micro USB), a *full on* USB-A to USB-B cable, which is what the Uno uses, *normally* do not come in a power-only configuration.
2. The port is damaged on the laptop. This is unlikely, but it worth checking by connecting a keyboard or mouse to the same port, to see if data is transferred
3. You have no driver installed. This is the most likely scenario. Normally the Arduino will trigger a driver to be automatically installed. However, in the case of the cheap Chinese clones, which use the CH340G chip, then the CH340 driver will need to be installed, if you are using Windows. Check the Device Manager in Windows to see if you Uno is recognised when connected, or whether is is shown as an "Unknown Device". A quick google should provide you with the correct driver for the CH340G. Please note that, if you are using Linux, then no driver is required, see [Majenko's answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/33069/safe-place-to-download-ch340g-drivers-from#answer-33072) to [Safe place to download CH340G drivers from](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/33069/safe-place-to-download-ch340g-drivers-from).